# Claat positive info box can't show correctly on html

Tags: markdown, google-codelab

I'm using claat to write a codelab, as I'm told by  [official doc](https://github.com/googlecodelabs/tools/tree/master/claat/parser/md), I can write like this to show a infobox:
[Colorful info boxes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZDQgB.png)

```
Positive
: This will appear in a positive info box.

Negative
: This will appear in a negative info box.
```

But when I write this and use claat tool to convert it to a HTML file, it just shows a text like this:
[just normal text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HFkEZ.png)

This is what I write:

```
Positive
: This will appear in a positive info box.
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears this was broken not by the css change, but rather by [this PR](https://github.com/googlecodelabs/tools/pull/456/) back in 2020, which changed the markdown format for specifying infoboxes. Unfortunately, it didn't preserve backward compatibility and no one seems to have caught that at the time.  One interesting thing to note is this change introduced a different markdown syntax for specifying infoboxes:

```
> aside positive
>
> Note: Your snappy text would go here.
```

```
> aside negative
>
> Note: Your snappy text would go here.
```

So, you can use the above native markdown syntax (I verified it works for me) if you prefer that for specifying infoboxes over embedded html aside elements.

Answer (score 0):

According to their [Markdown Parser doc](https://github.com/googlecodelabs/tools/tree/main/claat/parser/md#info-boxes), you can also use elements, which is good for multi-line InfoBoxes:

```html
<aside class="positive">
  This will appear in a positive info box.
  <p><code>single line code</code></p>
  <ul>
    <li>list item one</li>
    <li>list item two</li>
  </ul>
</aside>

<aside class="negative">
This will appear in a negative info box.
</aside>
```